# Slicing list of list in python, jumping one item

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm trying to reduce an important list of list in python as I don't need as much data to get where i want to go, ie drawing a route

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], 
          [15, 16], [17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]
```

I would like to "jump" some item of the list to reduce the size.
Example below where i skip 2 items every 3 lists.

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [7, 8], [13, 14], [19, 20]]
```

I tried with `mylist[1::3]` but wasn't successful

Thanks.

Comment: The index is 0 based - so you should use `mylist[0::3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting index was wrong - Python list indices start from 0. `mylist[0::3]`, or equivalently `mylist[::3]`, works just fine:

```
>>> mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18], [19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]

>>> mylist[::3]
[[1, 2], [7, 8], [13, 14], [19, 20]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist[::3]
```

works for me.

```
mylist[1::3]
```

goes to the first element and skips to every third after that, giving:

```
[[3, 4], [9, 10], [15, 16], [21, 22]]
```